# GLURaw failing due to missing header file

Tags: haskell, linker, haskell-stack, glu

I'm trying to use `gloss` which depends on `GLURaw`, and getting this error:

`stack install --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/nvidia-367 --extra-lib-dirs=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
/tmp/stack1018/GLURaw-2.0.0.2/cbits/HsGLURaw.c:74:20: error:
     fatal error: GL/glu.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
`cc' failed in phase `C Compiler'. (Exit code: 1)
```

I definitely have that file

```
locate glu.h
/nix/store/a4vqmz3737v3almi0pzawjgs9gdhprcr-glu-9.0.0-dev/include/GL/glu.h
/usr/include/GL/glu.h
```

and have no idea where to go from here. Googling about has not been helpful, and I don't have the low level knowledge of `cabal` or `ghc`'s means of interacting with C, to troubleshoot. Please help.

Comment: Try to add flag `--include-dirs=/usr/include` or `--include-dirs=/nix/store/a4vqmz3737v3almi0pzawjgs9gdhprcr-glu-9.0.0-dev/include`

Comment: If you are using `nix` (I do not use it so I can't say for certain) shouldn't it be the one to manage the setup of a proper environment for compilation? What does just `stack install GLURaw` give you?